# GStreamer/OpenCV | video to mkv and timestamp to file

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I use GStreamer and openCV to record videos of an Camera on NVIDIA Jetson. For this I capture the data in openCV (C++) and write the timestamp (ROS time, since ROS noetic is used as middle-ware) for each image in a text file after receiving the new image.
Unfortunately, I have now identified a mismatch between the number of timestamps written in the text file and the number of frames in the video. The captured video is de-composed to single images for further processing after recording the video data.

The reduced code to capture the video looks like follows:

```
sPipeLine = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw,width=(int)nWidth, height=(int)nHeight, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! appsink drop=1"; 

// Get the video data from GStreamer
cv::VideoCapture cap(sPipeline, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);

// Create a VideoWriter object, filename ends wit .mkv
cv::VideoWriter videoWriter(sVideoFileName, cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v'), 30, cv::Size(nWidth, nHeight));

int nSeq = 0;
std::ofstream outputFile(sTextFileName);

while (ros::ok())
{   
    // Read image data
    if (!cap.read(img)) {
        std::cout << "Capture read error" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    
    // Time stamping
    tTimeStamp.data = ros::Time::now();

    // Write the frame to the VideoWriter
    videoWriter.write(img);


    // Convert the time message to a string
    std::string timeString = std::to_string(tTimeStamp.data.sec) + "." +
                            std::to_string(tTimeStamp.data.nsec);

    timestampBuffer << nSeq << "," << timeString << std::endl; // e.g. 1234,1701357893.213058856
    
    // Flush the data to the file periodically to reduce IO operations
    if (nSeq % nFlushInterval == 0) {
          outputFile << timestampBuffer.str();

        // Clear the buffer and reset it
        timestampBuffer.str(std::string());
    }

    // Increment sequence counter
    nSeq++;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to capture the timestamps along with the video (ideally h264) directly with GStreamer without opencv?

I was also wondering about the behavior of the openCV VideoWriter as it requires a integer for FPS. While watching the frame rate with GStreamer, I saw that the frame rate fluctuates between 29.xx and 30.xx frames per second. I am afraid that this behavior courses the fact, that I have captured  67800 timestamps and 68087 frames in a recording of about 37.46 minutes.

Comment: no, the signatures of VideoWriter always have `double fps` -- you seem to want "presentation timestamps" (PTS). that's the actual truth in video streams. "FPS" is a fiction and guesswork that may be accurate for most videos but for some it's not because the sequence of PTSes is not isochronous.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the floating FPS. However, using a double does not solve the PTS problem you named. TBH, this presentation timestamp is totally new for me. Many thanks for this tip! Is there a solution available simply saving the video with its PTS information?

Comment: ffmpeg lets you do it all. opencv uses ffmpeg, gives a *simple* interface. that simple interface appears to be insufficient for what you need.